# Unit Test private methods in KMM project's commonTest module

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin-multiplatform, mockk

I'm trying to verify the shared module's private methods with Mockk. In the `AndroidApp` or `anroidMain` module, we could mark the private methods with `@VisibleForTesting` from `androidx.annotaion` to do the unit test.

What dependency should I add to the `commonMain` module to use the `@VisibleForTesting` or something similar?

Comment: have you tried adding `androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0-alpha02` to commonMain? it has being [released recently](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/04/whats-new-in-jetpack-multiplatform.html)